# git: is it possible to put files under a directory belonging to a submodule?

Tags: git

My project is using a library on github. So I am enlisting that library as a submodule. However, I want to put some files under that directory. The reason is that I'm using Bazel to build everything, but the library is using CMake. So I want to stick a BUILD file there to build the lib with Bazel.

When I do a `git add` there though, I'm getting an error saying that the folder belongs to a submodule. Essentially, I want to have a folder shared between the parent module and the submodule.

I know I can fork the library and add my BUILD file in my fork. But that workflow would require a little extra effort to maintain 2 repos. I wonder if there's a easier way to do this.

Comment: Create a build script that adds the file you need for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Git is not capable of this.  The reason is that the submodule entry for the directory is a commit with a special mode (160000), not a tree, as for a normal directory.  Thus, it's not possible to represent any such file under that directory since the entry is already used for the commit.

You can either fork the submodule or you can include build scripts in your project and copy them in with a script.